# ASP.NET Windows and Forms Autherntication

Tags: asp.net

I am using ASP.NET MVC and I using Forms authentication for active directory. However I need to use Windows authentication for one of my controllers and impersonate a user, is it possible to use both authentication and how can I do this?

In my web config I’ve tried this:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
    <identity impersonate="true" userName=“username” password=“password” />
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" loginUrl="~/Login/Index" timeout="45" slidingExpiration="false" protection="All" path="/" />
    </authentication>
```

but when I try to run my site, I get a 500 Internal server error. Please help! I just need to impersonate a user in one of my controllers. This controller does not need Active Directory authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forms authentication or Windows authentication is a configuration parameter of your server. You cannot have both authentication method on the same instance of your web application.
For your problem, check the matching between we.config file and IIS configuration.
Please add some configuration details to your post.
Cheers